# bootstrap dropdown button: How to hide dropdown menu when click other part of page?

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/components.html#buttonDropdowns

See the above link, when the `dropdown-menu` is shown, the outer div with `btn-group` will automatically add a class "open", when i click other part of the page, the "open" class is removed so the dropdown-menu disappears.

My question is `how to impl "click other part of page so the "open" class is removed?`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### You can use a simple JavaScript to reset:

```
$("body").click(function(){
    $(".open").removeClass("open");
});
```

I don't understand why you are asking this question, because, this is handled by BootStrap itself.

Comment: I extract some of its components to use, maybe it is handled by its js.

Comment: @PraveenKumar Bootstrap currenly listens for click events in the list elements or outside to close the dropdown automatically. In mobile devices the click event is not used. So until they fix this we'll have to close the dropdown manually.